# How to open local PDF file in PhoneGap (android)

Tags: android, pdf, cordova, sd-card

I'm trying to open a local PDF file stored in the sdcard. I tried everything possible but nothing seems to work.

I tried to open the pdf using the anchor tag  with external and _blank attribute.

I as well tried to "[WebIntent, an Android PhoneGap Plugin](http://smus.com/android-phonegap-plugins)". But was not able to succeed. I'm sure i have missed something in the manifest xml file. I'm not more into backend development. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here the answer : 
http://giovesoft.blogspot.com/2011/08/download-and-open-pdf-with-phonegap.html#more

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll check it out and update you if i'm successful in opening the PDF.