# Displaying PDF in phonegap

Tags: android, ios, cordova

May I know is there any other solution other then using childbrowser plugin to display a pdf in phonegap?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925174/how-to-open-local-pdf-file-in-phonegap-android

Answer (score 0):

I looked into this exact issue when developing an app that views PDF's. The childbrowser plugin is the best route. It's actually quite easy, and you can customize it any way that you'd like. Do you have a particular reason why you can't use the childbrowser?

From what I researched, you could also use 3rd party extensions to display pdf's, but in the end you'll still need to do most of what childbrowser plugin does, cause you will need to create a custom view that gets displayed when javascript is triggered.

Comment: As for 3rd party extensions, check out https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/1072 - it's a great way to display pdf, at least for iOS.